# MYSQL SELECT IF statement with AND

Tags: mysql

I have this query in mysql:

```
SELECT col1, col2, coletc, IF(a.status_working == 'normal', a.status_working == 'NN' AND a.status_working == 'overtime', a.status_working == 'OT') as status_working
```

My whole query:

```
HIDDEN for security reasons.
```

MYSQL return me an error. I need to make three condition if **status_working** = **'normal'** then write the output **NN**, if **status_working** == **'overtime'** then write the output **OT**, if **status_working** == **'overtime_s'** then write the output **OTS**

I'm not really good in mysql, so can someone help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: an if statement works like `IF( condition , true result, false result)` in your example you have 3 conditions `a.status_working == 'normal'` `a.status_working == 'NN' AND a.status_working == 'overtime'` and `a.status_working == 'OT'` you might be better off with a `case` statement https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html like... nvm someone just posted how to do that.

Comment: Your whole query is wrong. You are using `group by a.id` but you are selecting other columns without aggregate functions in select clause. Please read some tutorial on ` group by` and make your current query work. Then only you can think of adding `case`. All the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Case

```
SELECT col1, col2, coletc,
CASE status_working
  when 'normal' then 'NN'
  when 'overtime' then 'OT'
  when 'overtime_s' then 'OTS'
 END as status_working
 From your_table
```

Comment: I get the error when I run this query: `CASE a.status_working when 'normal' then 'NN' when 'overtime' then 'OT' END AS status_working, ROUND(a.act_hours, 1) AS 'act_hours', b.personnel_name` many unexpected token error comes up.

Comment: First run your query without the case statement. If you don't get any error without `case` then give your whole query. Else fix your rest of the query first.

Comment: Question edited. Whole query added to the question. Do you mind checking it out? thanks

Comment: I finally make it to work :D I change your query to something like this `(CASE WHEN a.status_working = 'normal' THEN 'NN' WHEN a.status_working = 'overtime' THEN 'OT' END) AS status_working` and mysql giving the result as I expected. thanks for your help, Sir.